# Too many output application using Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml

Running the app cause no problem but it shows a warning

> Too many Output!

Surprisingly when I check my phone because I use it as my deployment output instead of a virtual device, there are 3 application that was installed. Here's the screen shot.

[phone screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sXuf.jpg)

Here's my Java Codes

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.faacts.jayson.faactsv004;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button button;
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnglish);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Index.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
        }
}
```

**Splash.Java**

```
package com.faacts.jayson.faactsv004;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Jayson on 5/22/2016.
 */
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.rotate);
        final Animation an2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.abc_fade_out);

        iv.startAnimation(an);
        an.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                iv.startAnimation(an2);
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }


        });
    }
}
```

**Index.Java**

```
import android.text.method.HideReturnsTransformationMethod;
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by Jayson on 5/22/2016.
 */

public class Index extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtpassword;
    CheckBox chkbox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

        Button button;
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Registration.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
        chkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkBox);

        chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
                if (!isChecked) {
                    // show password
                    txtpassword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    chkbox.setText("Reveal Password");
                } else {
                    // hide password
                    txtpassword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                    chkbox.setText("Hide Password");
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Registration.Java**

```
package com.faacts.jayson.faactsv004;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

/**
 * Created by Jayson on 5/22/2016.
 */
public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);

        Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.gender_array,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        staticAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

    }
}
```

This is the example of my xml

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#33ccff"
    android:clickable="false"
    style="@style/AppTheme">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/welcomepage"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/welcomepage"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Choose your language:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="165dp"
        android:textColor="#003333"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnFilipino"
        android:id="@+id/btnFilipino"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnEnglish"
        android:id="@+id/btnEnglish"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Index"
    android:background="#33ccff"
    android:clickable="false"
    style="@style/AppTheme">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#33ccff">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgULogo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/upperlogo2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/upperlogo" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:textColorHint="@color/dim_foreground_material_dark"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="318dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:textColorHint="@color/dim_foreground_material_dark"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:text="@string/reveal_password"
        android:id="@+id/chkBox" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Please hoping for your feedback Anyway, I am new in android studio.
Anyway, there are two xmls that I did not post I just only pasted the example two those are the `registration.xml` and `splash.xml`.

**PROBLEM SOLVED:** I put a `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` instead of just a `DEFAULT` in every Java class on manifest declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.faacts.jayson.faactsv004">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Index">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Registration">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It's strange that 3 applications were installed on your phone. But, if you're getting the "Too much output to process" kind of message in the Logcat, you can use the spinner/selector to select the log messages just for your app.

Comment: Do they have different application IDs? Do you have a gradle build that has different build variants there? Like debug, release, etc?

Comment: Show us your Manifest file.

Comment: I will show you the manifest file but I'm still at school I will post it right away after I arrive home. I didn't bring my laptop.

Comment: Hi guys I already figure it out. The problem is on the manifest file hahaha silly me.

Comment: If you would like to answer your own question, please use the answer section below instead of an edit to the question. Thanks!